# Graylog2 ssh stream rules

Tags: graylog2

I have gotten a task to setup a new stream that catches all failed ssh logins. I have never used graylog before and iam really bad at regex.

I have figured out that you need to create a new stream, make so that all the failed ssh login messages gets caught in that stream and then make an alarm on that.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a stream just for an example then let us call it 
SSH accepted/failed

Then create a rule where you enter
field : messages
type : match regular expression
value for failed: Failed password for.+ from .+

and then create a new rule for the same stream with the value : Accepted password for.+ from .+

Then you will have a Stream there is collecting Failed and Accepted logins for your SSH

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/sshlog/agent/

It's a Linux daemon that monitors OpenSSH for logins, commands run, failed attempts, file uploads, etc.

Adapting their config sample for "send_to_syslog" you can configure the following to send all failed login attempts to Graylog via syslog:

```
# Description:
# Logs all events (e.g., login, command start, file upload) to a remote syslog server

events:
  - event: log_activity_to_syslog
    triggers:
      - connection_auth_failed
    filters:
      ignore_existing_logins: True
    actions:
      - action: syslog_to_graylog
        plugin: syslog_action
        server_address: address_to_graylog
        port: 5140
        udp: True
        output_json: False
        program_name: sshlog
```